# Report mojo is not executed on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, checkstyle

I am working in checkstyle,

I am using Jenkins, Maven 3.0.4. Checkstyle Jenkins plugin not installed.

I have 1 parent and 6 child projects.

I added checkstyle maven plugin to parentproject, childproject1, childproject6
in Parent:

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

in Child projects:

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>../parentProject/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

I run clean site command in my Eclipe,

It gave everything perfect what i expected. ie it giving checkstyle report for those 3 projects only.

Same code i copied to Jenkins workspace(job and workspace already) created.

it not working any thing it is creating for last project even not for checkstyle, creating for normal site plugin.  I am not able to understand why maven behavior is different for different locations even same version of it.

The log is:

## In Jenkins output:

```
tarted by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New
Updating http://mysvnurl/childProject2 at revision '2013-09-27T03:49:04.800 +0000'
At revision 5020
WARNING: clock of the subversion server appears to be out of sync. This can result in inconsistent check out behavior.
Updating http://mysvnurl/childProject3 at revision '2013-09-27T03:49:04.800 +0000'
At revision 5020
WARNING: clock of the subversion server appears to be out of sync. This can result in inconsistent check out behavior.
Updating http://mysvnurl/childProject4 at revision '2013-09-27T03:49:04.800 +0000'
At revision 5020
WARNING: clock of the subversion server appears to be out of sync. This can result in inconsistent check out behavior.
Updating http://mysvnurl/childProject7 at revision '2013-09-27T03:49:04.800 +0000'
At revision 5020
WARNING: clock of the subversion server appears to be out of sync. This can result in inconsistent check out behavior.
no change for http://mysvnurl/childProject2 since the previous build
no change for http://mysvnurl/childProject3 since the previous build
no change for http://mysvnurl/childProject4 since the previous build
no change for http://mysvnurl/childProject7 since the previous build
Parsing POMs
[childProject2] $ /mycompany/software/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/java -cp /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/mycompany/software/apache-maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /mycompany/software/apache-maven-3.0.4 /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.23.jar /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar 39163
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New/childProject2/pom.xml clean site
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building childProject2 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ childProject2 ---
[INFO] Deleting /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New/childProject2/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ childProject2 ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7

[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2' is invalid - Repository 'central2' will be blacklisted.

[CHECKSTYLE] No report found for mojo site

[JENKINS] Archiving site from /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New/childProject2/target/site to /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/jobs/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New/site

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.188s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 27 03:49:45 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/workspace/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New/childProject2/pom.xml to /opt/cibuild/.jenkins/jobs/Daily-myporjectModulesBuild-StaticAnalysis_New/modules/com.mycompany.mypro.services$childProject2/builds/2013-09-27_03-49-13/archive/com.mycompany.mypro.services/childProject2/1.5.0.0/childProject2-1.5.0.0.pom

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS


================================================================================================================================================
In Eclipse, output:
--------------------
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parentProject
[INFO] childProject1
[INFO] childProject2
[INFO] childProject3
[INFO] childProject4
[INFO] childProject5
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building parentProject 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ parentProject ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\workspaces\sitesMapTrunk\parentProject\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ parentProject ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] There are 243 checkstyle errors.
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Modules" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building childProject1 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ childProject1 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\workspaces\sitesMapTrunk\childProject1\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ childProject1 ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building childProject2 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ childProject2 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\workspaces\sitesMapTrunk\childProject2\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ childProject2 ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building childProject3 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ childProject3 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\workspaces\sitesMapTrunk\childProject3\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ childProject3 ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' is invalid - Repository 'com.springsource.repository.bundles.external' will be blacklisted.
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building childProject4 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ childProject4 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\workspaces\sitesMapTrunk\childProject4\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ childProject4 ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "Checkstyle" report    --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] There are 3 checkstyle errors.
[WARNING] Unable to locate Source XRef to link to - DISABLED
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' is invalid - Repository 'com.springsource.repository.bundles.external' will be blacklisted.
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building childProject5 1.5.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ childProject5 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\workspaces\sitesMapTrunk\childProject5\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) @ childProject5 ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
[WARNING] Report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin has an empty version.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Convergence" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Modules" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' is invalid - Repository 'com.springsource.repository.bundles.external' will be blacklisted.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parentProject ..................................... SUCCESS [22.917s]
[INFO] childProject1 ..................................... SUCCESS [11.073s]
[INFO] childProject2 ....................................... SUCCESS [14.076s]
[INFO] childProject3 .................................... SUCCESS [34.339s]
[INFO] childProject4 ...................................... SUCCESS [29.662s]
[INFO] childProject5 .................................... SUCCESS [28.539s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:20.837s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 27 16:47:10 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/449M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configure my svn project locations in different order instead of parent-child order.